# How do I print this pattern?Can anyone tell me the conditions(if statement)?

Tags: string, if-statement

I don't know how to print the second and third row.Please help.

```
****    
*  *  
*  * 
****

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)  
{  
if (i==1)||(i==n)  
{  
for(j=1;j<=n;j++)  
System.out.print(j);  
}  
else{  
//dont know
```

Comment: Please show some code you have tried.

Comment: I have done it.Please help!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
thank you but no thank you!
class patter
    {
        public static void main(int n)
        {
            int i,j;
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            {
                for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
                if(i==1||i==n)
                System.out.print("*");
                else
                {
                    if(j==1||j==n)
                    System.out.print("*");
                    else
                    System.out.print(" ");

                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```